# What HTTP redirect code should be used after tracking data collected?

Tags: redirect, http-headers

I have created a page which allows us to track where a visitor came from and then redirect to the original URL.

An example of what I have when you visit domain.com/page/*tracking-code* is:

- "*tracking-code*" stored in a cookie as their source location for later use
- redirected to "domain.com/page"

Currently PHP seems to have this as a 302 by default (found out this by using https://wheregoes.com/retracer.php) but I'm not sure if this is the best header code?

Comment: There are a lot of possible answers to this (in terms of tracking code handling). However, at face value, HTTP 302, it seems OK -- is it causing a problem?

Comment: Not causing any problems no, just I know 301's are strongly cached by the browser and didn't know if a 302 was the best solution. Thank you for answering though.